# pandas import error using Pycharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pycharm

I have issues of import pandas using Pycharm, but no issue of import pandas from command line, and I thought it might be caused by I installed multiple Python environment on my Mac. Wondering how to check on command line, which Python environment is used -- so that I can change my Pycharm environment according to the same environment which command line is using.

BTW, prefer to use Python 2.7.

Post screen snapshot for convenience.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit-1,

Post my PyCharm version and interpreter screen snapshot.

[image]
[image]

Edit-2,

I only have Default Setting under File menu, no item is called Setting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set proper python version that you want to use in pycharm at both console and run configurations.

**Console Configuration**
[image]

**Run Configuration**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks su79eu7k, vote up. How to check which version of Python my command line is using?

Comment: BTW, how to get your posted first Settings screen? Is it somewhere it PyCharm or in command line console (I am using iTerm for command line console)?

Comment: @LinMa Try `python -V` to check your python version at command line. and regarding the first setting screenshot, `File>Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Console>Python Console` or you can just input search term on the form at `Settings`.

Comment: Thanks su79eu7k , here is the output from Python -V, `$ python -V
Python 2.7.11 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.` Do you think it is the same Python environment which I select from PyCharm, which is 2.7.10 /usr/bin/python?

Comment: @LinMa I'm not sure but I don't think so...Continuum Analytics version seems one of anaconda(or miniconda2). Please try both.

Comment: Thanks su79eu7k, it seems console terminal is using different Python version from PyCharm. Is there a way I can change default Python version which console terminal (iTerm2) is using?

Comment: @LinMa As I know, even if your console terminal using different python version, you can assign another python interpreter on PyCharm even project by project. You should check about this first. Regarding changing default python it's possible with changing pythonpath, please refer to following article...(https://scipher.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/setting-your-pythonpath-environment-variable-linuxunixosx/)

Comment: Thanks for the patience to explain to me, su79eu7k. Vote up. I think your 2nd screen shows how to choose different Python runtime (Python interpreter), and my confusion is how your first screen (which is Python Console) related to this question? Do I have to set both Python runtime and Python Console? Thanks. :)

Comment: @LinMa Oops, I recognized your second screenshot as python console. Then you're right, you can run your script without my 1st screenshot. and you would be better to check your 1. pycharm default interpreter setting(near 1st screenshot), 2. project interpreter setting(near 1st screenshot), 3. run/debug configuration(2nd screenshot)

Comment: Thanks su79eu7k, post screen snapshots for my PyCharm version, and the only interpreter screen I found. It seems you have two screens related to interpreter (your bulletin points 1 and 2), if you could guide me where to find the other one, it will be great.

BTW, I do not find a Run Configuration either, it will be great you could share where do you find this screen? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa 1. File > Default Setting > Search 'interpreter' using upper left search box. There may be 'Project Interpreter'. 2. File > Setting > Search 'interpreter' using upper left search box. There may be 'Project Interpreter'. 3. Adding screenshot.

Comment: Thanks su79eu7k, so 1 is default interpreter and 2 is project specific interpreter? Why we need two and what are their relationship when we execute a Python script in PyCharm?

Comment: BTW, su79eu7k, I only have Default Setting under File menu, no item is called Setting. Any comments are appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi su79eu7k, if you could comment on my above question, it will be great. :)