# Run a Script using PyCharm terminal doesn't recognize pandas import

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm new in python. I using PyCharm and it's working fine. When I run a script with the "Run" tool (green bottom) it works, but I am curious how to run a script using `py my_script.py`.

I already tried using scripts without imported libraries and it worked. but when I have `import pandas as pd` on my Script it doesn't work. I went through several entries including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266416/pandas-import-error-using-pycharm) and my configuration seems to be ok. Also, it works with the green bottom.

This is what I get when I tried to run my simple script from PyCharm terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/load_data.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Any idea of what I'm missing?
I am over Windows 10

Comment: check your python version and find out same python version pandas library is install or not. If you using python3.x then your library will be installed inside that library packages.

Comment: inside pycharm see your interpreter setting and which version is using.

Comment: I checked PyCharm interpreter con console for the project and the interpreter is the same. Also, my packages are in the virtual environment of the project.

Comment: Find out package in library folder and copy paste to ur code folder. Try it